# More problems with querying zip codes in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I had asked a question about displaying zip codes with leading zeroes earlier. My problem at this point seems to be querying zip codes with different formats, not just displaying them. Some zips are entered like "15201" and some "15201-9998". The problem children seem to be the ones with leading zeroes "05201". I tried to convert the zip field to be a string field with the following code using the mongo console:

```
db.demographic.find({ Zip: { $exists: true }}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.Zip = "" + obj.Zip;
    db.demographic.save(obj); 
});
```

thinking that this would render all values in the zip field as strings. But sadly when I perform a query for a zip with leading zeroes, it comes up empty. This operation did convert the other zips with non-zero leading numbers however. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Your conversion would have converted 1234 to "1234", not "01234" - you left out the zero padding. Use the same logic I gave you yesterday to convert.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was thinking that 05201 would have been converted to "05201". Mongo seems to blow off the leading zero from the start, so the conversion just converted 5201 to "5201". I needed to remove the leading zero from the search, then re-insert it when displaying it. Thank you!!

Comment: `("00000"+zip).slice(-5)`